# Webmatrix/Razor - issues returning body

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix, braintree

I'm trying to write a quick page for a webhook response. The method needs to take the query string parameter, and pass back the response in the body. Here's what I have so far.

```
@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using Braintree;
@using System.Diagnostics;
@{
    Layout = "~/template";

    //Initialise Braintree Server SDK
    BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway
    {
        Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
        PublicKey = "xxx",
        PrivateKey = "xxx",
        MerchantId = "xxx"
    };

    return gateway.WebhookNotification.Verify(Request.QueryString["bt_challenge"]);

}
```

The problem is, when I run this page, I get the following error message:

> Since 'ASP._Page_Payments_Webhook_cshtml.Execute()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Answer (score 1):

Although i'm not familiar with everything thing you're are trying to do, i don't believe a cshtml page should be returning anything, thus the warning.  So try it exactly like the code you have, except for the last two lines.  Remove the return and instead:

```
@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using Braintree;
@using System.Diagnostics;
@{
    Layout = "~/template";

    //Initialise Braintree Server SDK
    BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway
    {
        Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
        PublicKey = "xxx",
        PrivateKey = "xxx",
        MerchantId = "xxx"
    };


}

@gateway.WebhookNotification.Verify(Request.QueryString["bt_challenge"]);
```